# NS [Network Simulator] TCL and C++

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2

i have written a protocol in c++ and would like to use NS to simulate and see the results.

i learned that TCL is the language used for it. I also found that C++ can be linked with TCL.

One of the method at  [link](http://mailman.isi.edu/pipermail/ns-users/2006-February/054169.html)  require to recompile the whole ns-package with the new cc files and doing some changes in some of the ns source files.

Is it required ? Would it take considerable time ? [more than 5 mins :( ]

Is there any better way ?

Comment: If you just want to see what is passed on the network, I recommend a program like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: my protocol in c++ is actually a distributed system protocol with nodes and messages exchanging between them. so i need to use ns.

Comment: You should be aware that we seem to be absent anyone with real expertise with ns2; I know I've got no idea at all on how to use it…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i learned that TCL is the language used for it. I also found that C++ can be linked with TCL.

Both Tcl and C++ are used. Tcl is for writing the simulation script, i.e. a file that sets us a specific simulation scenario, and C++ is used for writing the protocols that will be implemented.

> One of the method at link require to recompile the whole ns-package with the new cc files and doing some changes in some of the ns source files.
>
> Is it required ? Would it take considerable time ? [more than 5 mins :( ]

You can only avoid recompiling the whole package if you are using existing protocols, in which case you write a Tcl script to run your simulation. Since you want to implement a new protocol, you will definitely need to recompile the whole package.

In order to do this you will have to install Linux, if you don't already have it, or a Linux emulator like [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Then you should download and install the source code. I recommend the [ns2 allinone](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-build.html#allinone) package.

After the ns2 installation is working, you can start porting your protocol to ns2. A Good introductory tutorial for ns2 is [this](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/). Section VII covers creating new protocols for ns2.

So to answer your question

- Yes you will need to recompile from source
- Yes it will definitely take more that 5 minutes (Probably a few hours, depending on your experience).